# Using mailitem.PrintOut() to print a single page?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on a simple Outlook 2016/2019 VSTO plugin.

When an email is selected and a ribbon button is pressed, it needs to print just the first page of the email to the default printer. `mailitem.PrintOut();` works, but will print the whole email. Is there a way to specify the first page only?

```
var m = e.Control.Context as Inspector;
var mailitem = m.CurrentItem as MailItem;
if (mailitem != null)
{
    mailitem.PrintOut();
}
```

Update: See my answer for the code I used to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that. You need to parse the message body on your own and use .net mechanisms for printing this piece on your own.

Note, you may try using the Word object model for printing the message bodies (a specific range of pages). The [Document.PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout) method prints all or part of the specified document. Optional parameters allow specifying the page range.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the `Document` class from the Word object model which you can use to deal with the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly look at the Document.PrintOut method. I am also considering parsing the html and remove anything after a particular tag which would indicate a new message, but may not be super reliable.

Comment: I used the word object model, and have posted the code I used in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Eugene said, there's no way to specify a single page using mailItem.PrintOut.

I've finally managed to find a way to do this. I save the document as a .doc file in the temp directory, then using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to setup the page margins / size and then send the current page to the printer. Hopefully this helps someone as I couldn't find any working examples for c#!

```
private void btnPrintOnePage_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    string randFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "POP_" + RandomString(35) + ".doc";
        
    var m = e.Control.Context as Inspector;
    var mailitem = m.CurrentItem as MailItem;
    if (mailitem != null)
    {
        mailitem.SaveAs(randFile, OlSaveAsType.olDoc);

        Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document document = ap.Documents.Open(randFile);
        document.PageSetup.PaperSize = Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;
        document.PageSetup.TopMargin = 25;
        document.PageSetup.RightMargin = 25;
        document.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 25;
        document.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 25;
            
        Word.WdPrintOutRange printRange = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintCurrentPage;

        document.PrintOut(false,null,printRange);
        document.Close(false, false, false);
        File.Delete(randFile);

    }

}

public static string RandomString(int length)
{
Random random = new Random();
const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```